# How to use a 2-join table method with MVC in controller?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller

Kind of a complicated question to ask.

So there's a class for `Car`, `CarDAL`(data access layer). A interface layer for `User`, `IUserDAL`. And a business logic class `User`.

For MVC I got `CarsController` and `CarModel`.

`CarDAL`, which basically adds a car, gets the id and connects it with the linking table which connects it with an user:

```
public void AddCar(int userID, CarDTO carDTO)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        string query = "DECLARE @ID TABLE(CarID INT) " +
            "INSERT INTO[dbo].[auto](Price, Addition, License_Plate, MaxKm, Type, Color, NumberOfSeats, Fueltype, reservationStatus, ModelID) " +
            "OUTPUT INSERTED.CarID INTO @ID " +
            "VALUES(@Price, @Addition, @LicensePlate, @MaxKm, @Type, @Color, @NumberOfSeats, @FuelType, @Reserved, @ModelID) " +
            "INSERT INTO[dbo].[User_Car](UserID, CarID, Role, Favorite) " +
            "SELECT @UserID, c.CarID, 'verkoper', 0 FROM @ID c";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", carDTO.Price);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addition", carDTO.Addition);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicensePlate", carDTO.License_Plate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaxKm", carDTO.MaxKilometres);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", carDTO.Type);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Color", carDTO.Color);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberOfSeats", carDTO.NumberOfSeats);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FuelType", carDTO.Fueltype);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReservationStatus", carDTO.ReservationStatus);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModelID", carDTO.ModelID);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userID);
        }
    }
}
```

`Logic`:

```
IUserDAL<UserDTO, CarDTO> userDAL;

public void AddCar(int userID, CarDTO c)
{
    userDAL.AddCar(userID,
                new CarDTO(c.Color, c.Type, c.NumberOfSeats, c.Price, c.MaxKilometres, c.Addition, c.ModelID, c.License_Plate, c.Fueltype, c.ReservationStatus));
}
```

And in the controller I need to make a connection with a specific user that already exists in the database and connect it with the car. At first thought I just tried to `User user = new User(???);` but than I didn't know what to fill in to get the `UserID` from a user in the database with certain info.

Context: The function that I want is that you'd basically log in and add a car for sale and than the car would be connected to your `UserID`, but I don't know how to get the `UserID` without having to log in yet.

So what I have now in the `CarsController` is:

```
User user = new User(); //<- there needs to be a parameter of type UserDTO and I don't know what to fill in there.

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddCar(CarModel car)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        user.AddCar(1, 
                    new DTO.CarDTO(car.Color, car.Type, car.NumberOfSeats, car.Price, car.MaxKilometres, car.Addition, car.ModelID, car.License_Plate, car.Fueltype, car.ReservationStatus));
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}
```

And last in `CarModel` I have:

```
public EnumsDTO.Color? Color { get; set; }
public EnumsDTO.Type? Type { get; set; }
public int? NumberOfSeats { get; set; }
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
public int? MaxKilometres { get; set; }
public decimal? Addition { get; set; }
public int? ModelID { get; set; }
public string? License_Plate { get; set; }
public EnumsDTO.Fuel? Fueltype { get; set; }
public bool ReservationStatus { get; set; }
```

**tl;dr**
I want the function that you can add a car to the database but the car obviously has a seller so it needs to be connected by logging in. So logging in should be made first, I think. But the main important function is that you can add a car and connect it together with an user in the database. The problem is that I don't know how to put it in code in the controller.

p.s. also if anyone can formulate the question better please tell me.

Comment: You want perform insert operations based on table  join?

Comment: @jishansiddique yes but that's not really the problem...I dont know how to put it in code in the controller